# Isabelle console Thy_info.use_thy can't process server response

Tags: isabelle

I am working using Isabelle console to load theories `Thy_Info.use_thy` and some of the theories fail when getting response from Isabelle server

```
### theory "CParser.TypHeap"
### 2.100s elapsed time, 10.446s cpu time, 0.000s GC time
*** exception Fail raised (line 66 of "System/isabelle_system.ML"): Malformed result from bash_process server
*** At command "apply" (line 1521 of "/workspace/l4v/tools/c-parser/umm_heap/TypHeap.thy")
Exception-
   CONTEXT
     (<context>,
      EXCURSION_FAIL
        (CONTEXT
           (<context>, Fail "Malformed result from bash_process server"),
         "At command \"apply\" (line 1521 of \"/workspace/l4v/tools/c-parser/umm_heap/TypHeap.thy\")"))
   raised
Poly/ML>
```

When I run `Isabelle build` with that specific theory in the ROOT file it succeeds but `use_thy` still fails.
I've also seen this error from `Isabelle client`

```
 *** Malformed message header: "OK {"isabelle_id":"c2a2be496f35","isabelle_name":"Isabelle2021-1"}"
*** At command "by" (line 139 of "~/workspace/l4v/lib/More_Numeral_Type.thy")
```

When I run `isabelle build` I see bash processes being completed without server running.
When does a theory require a serve and any ideas the issues with my configuration?

Is there a way to interact with Isabelle server programmatically sending ML code to be executed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The server is only needed for interactive sessions, not for batch builds. The server is also not needed for the Isabelle console, which is a separate application.

The Isabelle console is the only way to interact with the server.

In this case, to process the response from the server, the Isabelle console needs to know the exact format of the response. This is not part of the Isabelle build system, but part of the Isabelle console. The Isabelle console is a separate application, not part of the Isabelle build system.

Comment: That make sense but I don't understand why would console not understand the response from the server?  They are both part of Isabelle and both app should be able to interact with each other

Comment: The console is a very simple interface to the Isabelle system. It is not intended to be a general-purpose interface to the Isabelle server. The console is not a client of the server, it is a server itself.

Comment: I am not sure about that.  When I configure `bash_process_address` and `password` in the options file console will fail with malformed error otherwise fail for not able to connect to the server .. Same with `Isabelle process` command